# Under FOC control, can current sampling be removed when the inductance of the motor is small?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, motor-controller, induction-motor

I have dismantled a micro coreless servo motor produced by SIEMENS and made a copy of it. Then I designed an FOC driver board using single shunt and transplant the FOC algorithm to make a position control of the motor. Then I added position loop before the current loop, and the motor has slight noise probably because the current sampling is not that accurate.

So I tried to remove the current sampling and set the three-phases current to 0. Then I found by chance the motor has no noise and the perfomance of position control is still good.

I wonder if the current sampling is necessary when the motor has a small inductance?

---

Here is a related introduction by simpleFOC.

https://docs.simplefoc.com/voltage_torque_control

I wonder under what situation can it work well?

Comment: What acceleration and load was used for your test?  Current can range over 100:1  But Neutral balance tolerances depend on motor specs and perhaps Remenance from abrupt stops

Comment: Does the motor have an encoder? Or are you estimating position using an observer?

Comment: @mkeith,Yes,I measure the position by a magnetic sensor.

Comment: The problem with voltage torque control is that a small error in back emf estimation or DC-link voltage measurement could lead to a large error in torque. Also, an error in the winding resistance will lead to an error in torque. And the winding resistance changes with temperature of the wire (4 percent every 10 degrees K). The one person I know who tried it found it was not reliable under dynamic loads.